# jQuery : hover event not work for appended object with ajax request

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

Hi, the jQuery hover event not working for appended object via ajax .

I add `<div class="item ..."> ... </div>` with

**Ajax call:**

```
 var jqxhr = $.ajax( '{{ path('nextPage_url') }}'+page )
              .always(function(data) { 
                  $("#container").append(data).masonry('reload');
               });
```

**Hover Event delegation :**

I have hovered over  `.item`  class elements,it
works fine for preloaded data,but for new `<div>` added via ajax  request its not working

```
        $('.item').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).addClass('img-polaroid-shadow').removeClass('img-polaroid');
            },
            function(){
                $(this).removeClass('img-polaroid-shadow').addClass('img-polaroid');
            }
        );
```

Thanks

Comment: Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with event delegation

Comment: i write this `$('.item').on('hover',function(){  alert(2); } );` and not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added element, so:

```
$(document).on(
{
    mouseenter: function() 
    {
        $(this).addClass('img-polaroid-shadow').removeClass('img-polaroid');
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass('img-polaroid-shadow').addClass('img-polaroid');
    }
}
, '.item');
```

Comment: Thanks Eli, but what's difrent between your code and my code?

Comment: Your code only binds a handler to the elements that are returned by the `$(".item")` selector when the page is first loaded. New elements aren't in that collection.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you applied the event handler and the page loaded, the elements which existed before were seen by JavaScript and thus it applied handlers to only those elements.

However, when you appended an item (element) to the page, it wasn't on the list of the DOM. Thus, you need to use Event Delegation in this case.

Simply use jQuery's `.on()` or `.delegate()` methods. If you want to know how it works then [go here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-event-delegation-in-4-minutes/) for a simple jQuery tutorial (not a reference, just a recommendation).

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
$(document).on('mouseover','span', function () {
        $(this).css('color','#CCC');
    });
    $(document).on('mouseout','span', function () {
        $(this).css('color','#000');
    });
```

Working sample on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HpL7X/